# Stripe_Charge::create error in PHP

Tags: php, ssl, stripe-payments

Stripe payments on our live e-commerce site have started failing 100% of the time with:

```
ERROR - 2015-06-02 10:56:20 --> Stripe_ApiConnectionError Object
(
    [message:protected] => Unexpected error communicating with Stripe.  If this problem persists, let us know at support@stripe.com.

(Network error [errno 77]: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?))

....
```

The error is thrown from `[application]/libraries/stripe/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php`

The server is running CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

It refers to an SSL CA cert - but our certs are not installed on the server because SSL is terminated on a proxy. We have not changed any application code since last week, when it was working OK. However we did install some system updates.

What's confusing is that it points to an SSL problem, yet SSL is not terminated on the web server. Can anyone advise?

Comment: Did you restart you apache or nginx and fpm? And what is your php version?

Comment: Restarting Apache does appear to have fixed it. Perhaps I forgot to restart it after installing the server updates (that included openssl).

Also, it is PHP 5.5.17 (cli) (built: Sep 20 2014 17:12:00)